# Why can't my iPhone connect to the mail server anymore (and how can I fix it)?

Tags: iphone, email

A few days ago my iPhone stopped downloading new emails.  The Mail app now brings up an error:

> **Cannot Get Mail**
>
> The connection to the server failed.

Though it can't connect to the server to *download* or *send* emails, it can connect to *verify* my username and password:

[image: email account verified on iphone]

---

This email address is working just fine using my laptop.

Some things I've tried that didn't fix the problem:

- going into airplane mode and back out
- restarting the device
- reentering my mail account settings
- deleting the mail account and creating a new one

Some specs:

- iPhone 5
- iOS 7.1.2
- email provider: Yahoo
- service provider: AT&T

Comment: If it can verify, then the most likely option is that the Advanced data is wrong - SSL, Port etc. Did you check Yahoo haven't changed their details without telling you. My ISP did just that last year

Comment: First thing I'd check is SMTP settings with your e-mail provider.

Answer (score 1):

Settings → General → Reset → Reset Network Settings.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: It may not be in the correct format, but it's the only advice after much searching and testing that actually solved the issue for me!